# Can use of AKAudioFile and replaceWith within AKAudioPlayer lead to distortion?

Tags: audiokit

I'm building AudioKit into an experimental psychology add testing interoception (internal body sense), and it's very simple for now, I just have an AudioManager.m class that declares:

```
    @implementation AudioManager {
    AKAudioPlayer* player;
    bool canPlay;
}

    +(AudioManager *)sharedManager {
        static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
        static AudioManager *instance = nil;
        dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
            instance = [[AudioManager alloc] init];
            [instance setup];
        });
        return instance;
    }
```

little player methods like:

```
-(NSError*)playHTTIntro {
    return [self playWavInResources:@"Htt1"];
}
```

are then invoked from particular view controllers as:

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[AudioManager sharedManager] playHTTGuess];
}
```

the weird problem I'm having is that as files get called and played, increasing amplitude and distortion accumulates

by the time I've played 10 or 15 files, the voice audio files are almost impossible to understand

the `playWavInResources`above is implemented as:

```
    -(NSError*)playWavInResources:(NSString*)wavName {
    if(player)
        [player stop];

    NSError* error;
    AKAudioFile* audioFile = [[AKAudioFile alloc] initForReading:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:wavName ofType:@"wav"]] error:&error];
    if(!error) {
        if(player)
            [player replaceWithFile:audioFile error:&error];
        else
            player = [[AKAudioPlayer alloc] initWithFile:audioFile looping:false lazyBuffering:false error:&error completionHandler:nil];
        AudioKit.output = player;

        // Start audio engine if not already
        NSError* error;
        [AudioKit startAndReturnError:&error];
        if(!error)
            [player start];
    }
    return error;
}
```

Has anyone seem this problem before?

Comment: I haven't seen that before but I believe you, I'm just wondering if you can share a public project that demonstrate the issue so I can test it myself and see if I can track down the problem.